# Find last 1800 second(30 minutes) data in a log table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, salesforce

I have a table with a `log_date` column (`dd mm-yy-hh-m-ss` format)

What I have tried is:

```
select * from dum where(sysdate-log_date)<=1/48;
```

But does not worked at all so please suggest what should i use?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM dum WHERE log_date BETWEEN (SYSTIMESTAMP - 1800/(24*60*60)) AND SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `LOG_DATE` column is of `DATE` data type, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUM
WHERE  log_date >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;
```

If your `LOG_DATE` column is a `VARCHAR2` then just wrap it in `TO_DATE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUM
WHERE  TO_DATE( log_date, 'dd mm-yy-hh-mi-ss' ) >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;
```

*(and then look at changing your table to use a `DATE` data type to store dates rather than using strings.)*